# How to load balance a request on a service to a pod depending on a condition

Tags: kubernetes

I have an app with 3 nodes running with a service, which uses zookeeper to elect a leader. And I want the requests to the service to be redirected to a certain pod, depending if it's leader or not. I have a http method in my app that returns if it's leader or not (if this helps in any way).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a k8s feature for doing this.

What I would do:
write a little application which looks for the endpoints of the existing service, searches the current leader, and creates/updates a 2nd service without selector (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors) with an endpoint pointing to the leader. Then you can use that new service for your dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, you're saying to use something like a cron job to continuously search and update the leader, right?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#schedule like this

Comment: not sure if I would create a long running application which periodically looks for the leader, or use a cronjob which looks once for the leader... probably doesn't make a big difference.


Another thought: I'm not that familiar with zookeeper, maybe it's even possible to watch for changes there directly, with a long running http request or websocket? That would be nicer than polling, because you could update the service immediately after a leader change instead of after the next poll.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, use a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/), for example, following the [example here](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/statefulsets/zookeeper).

Comment: Yes, i'm using a StatefulSet to deploy my app. Maybe I haven't expressed well my problem. My app has a dashboard, but this dashboard can only be accessed with the leader. That means, when I try to access the dashboard using the service, sometimes it works well and sometimes doesn't (because of the load balance of the service, sometimes it reaches the leader and sometimes it reaches the replicas/slaves). So, is there a way where I can configure the service to load balance the requests only to the leader of my app? Thank you for now